# Why is New-SelfSignedCertificate is missing parameter -Type?

Tags: powershell, parameters, certificate

I try to sign my ps.1 file and wanted to create a code signing certificate but my `New-SelfSigningCertificate` does not have the parameter `-Type` in the function. 
I use PowerShell 5.1.

When I use `Get-Help`, the description oddly enough also displays much less parameters than on the microsoft website. Opening the online help via `Get-Help` does not work because the URI is not specified.

The Help content:

```
SYNTAX
    New-SelfSignedCertificate [-DnsName <string[]>] [-CloneCert <Certificate>] 
    [-CertStoreLocation <string>] [-WhatIf] [-Confirm]  [<CommonParameters>]
```

Am I using an outdated version? Is this command only properly available in Win 10 or Server 2016?

Comment: according to the MSDocs site, the `-Type` parameter is only available on win10. the cmdlet is also on win8 & win8.1 ... but has a far smaller list of parameters - and `-Type` is not one of them.

Comment: you are most welcome! glad to kinda-sorta help ... [*grin*]